# If $M\in \mathcal M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ invertible, why is there $c>0$ s.t. $|Mx|\geq c|x|$.

Tags: functional-analysis

My question is probably obvious, but if $M\in \mathcal M_{n\times n}(\mathbb R)$ invertible, why is there $c>0$ s.t. $|Mx|\geq c|x|$ for all $x$. Trying with the inverse operator $M^{-1}$ as suggested Mehta : set $x=M^{-1}y$.

$$|M^{-1} y|\leq \|M^{-1}\||y|\leq \underbrace{\min\{|\mu _1|,...,|\mu _n|\}}_{:= c}|y|$$
where $\mu_i\neq 0$ are eigenvalue of $M^{-1}$ and where I used the equivalence of the normes in the last inequality. Now $$\frac{1}{c}|M^{-1}y|\leq |y|\implies \frac{1}{c}|x|\leq |Mx|.$$

Does it work ?

Comment: Is $|\lambda_1|$ largest or smallest?  Which one would tell you about *lower* bounds?

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Think about the operator norm of $M^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

If there was no such $c>0$, then there would exist a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $|Mx_n| < \tfrac 1 n|x_n|$ for all $n$. Let $u_n := \tfrac{x_n}{|x_n|}$. Then $|Mu_n| < \tfrac 1 n$ for each $n$. As $|u_n|=1$, there exists a convergent subsequence $(u_{n_k})$. Let $u$ denote its limit. Then $|Mu| = \lim_k|Mu_{n_k}|\le\lim_k\tfrac 1{n_k} = 0$, i.e., $Mu=0$. But $M$ is invertible and so $u=0$. But $|u| = \lim_k|u_{n_k}|=1$, a contradiction.

Comment: I like your answer, good job ! (+1) Unfortunately, it doesn't really help on how $c$ can be neither on how look such a $c$. In that, the answer of Mehta is a little bit more precise (that's why I accepted his answer and not yours).